# Response variable (Before,during, after) is it ordinal or multinomial?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, ordinal-data, multinomial-distribution

Hi I am looking at elemental concentrations in pectoral fin rays the year before spawn, year of spawn, and the year after spawn. I will be creating a logistic regression model to see if I can predict the year related to spawn using the elemental concentrations measurements. Would the response variable (year before, spawn year, year after) be ordinal or multinomial?

Answer (score 1):

Your response variable is ordinal because there is clear ordering to it: before -> during -> after. You'd typically fit an ordinal logistic regression to this kind of data, though sometimes it is convenient to treat it otherwise (e.g. as continuous).

A multinomial logistic would be called for if your response variable had categories with no ordering e.g. apple/banana/orange.